# May Jews do their obligation of purim intoxication with smoking some marijuana

Tags: halacha, purim, tractate-megillah, intoxication, marijuana

According to Halacha, a Jew over bar mitzvah should get at least mildly intoxicated on Purim, my question is, can this obligation be fulfilled by smoking some marijuana? Or does it have to be alcohol intoxication only?

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6393/759 (this question would only work for poskim who allow other forms of alcohol)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10609/ and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59027/

Comment: This question would be more compelling if it included support for its initial Halachic assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to shitas you need wine to do the mitzva (as some are midayik from rashi, and their reason being since the neis came about through wine) it's obvious you cant do mitzva other ways. (Ksav Sofer, Mikrai Kodesh..) Especially according to Rav Yisrael Salanter that holds the mitzva is to just keep on drinking,  and when you reach ad dilo yada you're exempt since a shoteh is exempt from mitzos. (As brought in emek bracha)
Even those that hold mitzva can be done with other alcoholic beverages, the mitzva is to be drunk ad dilo yado. You can't just go to sleep without drinking and fulfill the Mitzvah. Chazal were misaken to be ad dilo yada through being drunk not high. You can see from google that there's diffrences between being drunk and high.

Comment: @Kirk everyone agrees that it has to be through drinking.  Just like if you just go to sleep, your not yotza. Why? Because you need to get there through drinking. Because thats how chazal made the mitzva.